# How many dead horses will the Horse God, Malanya, remember?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

After paying to unlock Malanya, the Horse God, you can revive horses that you had boarded that have reached a state of no longer living.  Is there some kind of limit on how many horses are available to be revived?  For example, if I've had 2 horses die, can I revive them both?  What about 10? and 100? 1,000?

Comment: I've only been able to find sources saying "Any" horse you've boarded.  I assume that concludes to "all."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After doing *science* on several horses, I've concluded that the horse god will only remember the last 5 horses that have died while registered.

First, I had 1 horse that had died honorably in battle.

[image: First meeting]

Next up, add a horse to the list.

[image: first science]

New horse is added to the bottom. Good to know.

[image: continued science]

After 5 new horses, the first horse is no longer available to revive. Note that this menu does not scroll. Also of note, horses are listed in order they died, not alphabetically or any other way.

[image: mad science]

After 5 more horses had fallen to *science*, all 5 previous horses had been removed as options.

### Conclusion

In total, 12 horses had fallen (11 intentionally fed bombs) and a max of 5 were available to revive.  Those 5 were the most recent, not the best stats or anything like that.

As a side note, the horse god had some unique dialogue, which [a video corroborates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l--Tse_XBN8&t=61s), when trying to revive a bombed horse, but never brought down any wrath.

> Oh, goodness! It was caught in an explosion? Poor soul... Not to cast suspicion where none is warranted, but... you didn't kill the horse did you? It couldn't be the case. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. Would you like to revive this horse?

Comment: Too bad you didn't revive one on the list of #1 through #5, to check whether or not cream will reappear.

Comment: @Hurkyl I smell more *science* needing to be done!  Since the list is populated in order of death, I imagine revives remove from the list and upon death that are added to the bottom.

Comment: After so many horses gave their live for sience, if you now revive one, will Malanyas Memory-list now shrink to 4, or will one, that was pushed out at the top, will appear back on the list?

Comment: I found out something interesting:
It seems like the unique horses, which have their own entries in the Hirule compendium, are never pushed out of the list, in my case there are now six horses, and it scrolls.
For me it looks like Malanya can remember all 4 unique horses + up to 5 normal random ones.